# Where is seek method in AVRO 1.8.2 python3 API?

Tags: python-3.x, avro

I do see there is a seek method at 1.2 api version, https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/py/avro.io.html, but it seems that it's gone at 1.8.2, is there any other alternative?

```
from avro.io import DatumReader    
dir(DatumReader)
    Out[20]: 
    ['__class__',
     '__delattr__',
     '__dict__',
     '__dir__',
     '__doc__',
     '__eq__',
     '__format__',
     '__ge__',
     '__getattribute__',
     '__gt__',
     '__hash__',
     '__init__',
     '__init_subclass__',
     '__le__',
     '__lt__',
     '__module__',
     '__ne__',
     '__new__',
     '__reduce__',
     '__reduce_ex__',
     '__repr__',
     '__setattr__',
     '__sizeof__',
     '__str__',
     '__subclasshook__',
     '__weakref__',
     '_read_default_value',
     'check_props',
     'match_schemas',
     'read',
     'read_array',
     'read_data',
     'read_enum',
     'read_fixed',
     'read_map',
     'read_record',
     'read_union',
     'reader_schema',
     'set_reader_schema',
     'set_writer_schema',
     'skip_array',
     'skip_data',
     'skip_enum',
     'skip_fixed',
     'skip_map',
     'skip_record',
     'skip_union',
     'writer_schema']
```